# How to deal with the profile name not matching the cc name?

Tags: laravel-spark

Laravel Spark 6

Using Braintree, but I think Stripe will be the same.

It seems odious to expect the profile name to match the credit card name. But it seems the case that you cannot add a payment method unless the profile name and the cc name match.

It seems easiest to just ask for the name on the card in the payment method dialog.

I know that you control whether or not the cvv is asked for from the Braintree dashboard. Is there a similar way for asking for the name?

Or do i have to go into the code for getting and submitting the cc information?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Braintree and Stripe are different.

As of this time, Braintree doesn't seem to accept a user name at all.